# Oracle SQL - removing duplicates from a messy query

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have a long complex (for me at least) query which returns the exact data I need. Only problem is some ids are being duplicated due to one join in the query having a many to one relationship. What I'd like to do is just take the output from the query, and select one row per unique ID. It really doesn't matter how this row is selected from the duplicate IDs, I just need it to be reduced to one row per ID in the simplest way possible.

In other words I have a long messy query that gives me the data I need with neatly named columns etc BUT duplicated IDs:

```
ID    column1  column2 column2...  column50
111    data    data    data   ...  data
111    data    data    data   ...  data
112    data    data    data   ...  data
113    data    data    data   ...  data
113    data    data    data   ...  data
113    data    data    data   ...  data
```

And I want to take this output from the query and reduce it to

```
ID    column1  column2 column2...  column50
111    data    data    data   ...  data
112    data    data    data   ...  data
113    data    data    data   ...  data
```

The challenge I'm having is that I don't know how to take the entire output from a query and do stuff with it (like remove duplicates) without first writing it to a table, and I'm not able to write to a table.

Comment: You have to specify how to chose each id's row. (rowno perhaps?)

Comment: Also, editing your question to provide a (short!) example of your query to go along with your sample data would help. Also, it would help if you could supply some sample data that accurately replicated your issue on a small scale - for example, your "duplicated" rows, do they have the same data for each column? Or can the data be different, eg. (id = 111, col1 = 'a', col2 = 10) id = 111, col1 = 'a', col2 = 20)? If the latter, which row would you want to be picked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is identical then the simplest way is to wrap your messy query in another query where you just use `SELECT DISTINCT`. like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM   (
  your_messy_query
)
```

If it is not identical then you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY something ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    your_messy_query
  ) t
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The `ORDER BY something` could be:

- a specific set of columns if you how to retrieve the most appropriate data;
- or you could use `ORDER BY ROWNUM` if you just want to take the first row of each group;
- or `ORDER BY NULL` if you want a non-deterministic order - however, this typically seems to be implemented with the same effect as `ORDER BY ROWNUM`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at the second case (it's not identical), but I'm getting "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected". I changed my messy query to just be "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER" to keep it simple and I keep getting the same error - here is the full query
...


SELECT * 
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER
  
  ) t
)
WHERE rn = 1;

Comment: never mind, I found the missing comma after "SELECT t.*"

Comment: NP thanks so much for your help, glad I could be of some use at least lol